# Making a python module to open a website

Tags: python

```
def Google(x):
from webbrowser import *
if x == Google:
    open_new("https://www.google.com")
elif x== Tinker:
    open_new("https://www.tinkercad.com")
```

I named this module Alpha, simply to make it easy to remember.

I have had no problems calling this module, the place I have had trouble is calling the second part; Tinker
[Trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzTPL.png)

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: `NameError: Tinker`

Comment: you should use like `x== 'Tinker'` && `x== 'Google'`. `x` is your parameter name

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean these to be strings.

```
if x == "Google":
    open_new("https://www.google.com")
elif x == "Tinker":
    open_new("https://www.tinkercad.com")
```

(The first one only didn't give an error because it reused the name of your function.)

Comment: Thank you for this, I wasn't sure if it was supposed to be a string. But sadly this hasn't fixed my problem.